# All the pod metrics to automatically include labels from kube_pod_labels?

Tags: prometheus, kube-state-metrics

I've added custom labels for kube-state-metrics by adding:

```
--metric-labels-allowlist=deployments=[team],pods=[team]
```

which means I can see the "label_team" label within `kube_pod_labels` and `kube_deployment_labels` metrics.

Now, if I'd like to use "label_team" within alerts, I'd need to group metrics in each expression like explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53151782/2884309).

Is there a way to include these custom labels in all the metrics automatically?

Somehow to tell kube-state-metrics to inject custom labels into all pod/deployment metrics...? I was thinking if it's possible with "relabelings" or "metricRelabelings" options within kube-state-metric's ServiceMonitor.